# In what cases do we use the GET method?

Tags: post, get, http-headers

When taking input we can use either GET or POST.The input is shown in the URL when using GET but not when POST is used.Is there a situation where GET is more useful than POST? Where using either POST or GET might not be a good idea?

Comment: For one thing - you won't want to send passwords through GET.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but what I want to know is there something where GET has an edge over POST?

Comment: GET is useful where all info to process the request needs to be in the URL, for example when you click a package tracking URL in your mail program and want all parameters like tracking number to be contained in the URL. POST would require an URL + data to post to do the same thing.

Comment: GET is also generally used for getting data, while POST is used for updating/creating data. The distinction is very useful for caching for example, where a `GET` of a home page can be cached, while a `POST` with login information when you log in should probably *not* be cached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function of both the methods is same but `the difference lies between the two in terms of how the form data is submitted`, is explained as follows:

1.**GET** method is used to submit the data appended to a URL. The data filled by the user appears after a question mark in the browser (called a query-string). The benefit of this method is that the data can be changed in the link address itself rather than going to a form again and editing data there (or submitting an AJAX request).

2.In the case of the **POST** method, the data does not appear in the browser address bar. This is, thus, a better method for a login form because in this case the user is entering a username and password and these should not be shown in the browser address bar.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP

**Edited.**

**GET:**

- Can be bookmarked.
- Using the GET method works great for emails since you can't use JS or forms in most email applications.
- GET method should not be used when sending passwords or other sensitive information as it will be visible in the browser UI.
- 7607 character maximum size.
- Url example: page2.php?category=sport

**POST:**

- Can not be bookmarked.
- Using forward/back buttons in the browser that hit pages loaded with POST data will require a refresh of the page since the browser knows/thinks that the POST data is something that the server needs to create the page.
- POST method used when sending passwords or other sensitive information. Note that using the POST method does not ensure privacy, the data is still readily accessible and in plain text, just not visible in the URL.
- 8 Mb max size for the POST method.
- Url example: page2.php
- POST data won't be tracked in analytic data.

Answer (score 2):

**GET** is mainly used when the parameters that are put into the URL can speed-up searching a website or create shortcuts for the users.

In a search function it's good practice to send the data using **GET** as a user can simply change the URL to search something different. In the example below the word *car* can be substituted to perform a different search.

`www.domain.com/search?query=cars`

In cases where it would not be advantageous to have the parameters displayed **POST** should always be used. Especially for sensitive information.

Answer (score 2):

There is 1 scenario that GET can do which POST can't. If you need to submit to server which need to be able to be bookmarked.

For example, you have a "view" which is a result of a set of filter and you would like to be able to bookmark in your browser such that you want to be able to return to that view right from bookmark. You wouldn't be able to do it using POST, but you will be able to do it with GET.

Comment: That's true for deep-linking from external sources as well. Google will not index your page with POST variables but it will with GET ones.

Answer (score 1):

By using the GET method you are able to edit the content sent afterwards.

Say for example you have file creating dynamic widgets for customers to use on their own webpages, it would be pretty hard to get them using POST to get their iframe content instead of just making a GET request ex: `http://widgetGenerator.com?customer=domain.com`

The examples are unlimited, but this could be one case.